# Canonical way to reduce number of ID variables in wide-format data

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I have data organized by two ID variables, `Year` and `Country`, like so:

```
Year Country VarA VarB
2015     USA    1    3
2016     USA    2    2
2014  Canada    0   10
2015  Canada    6    5
2016  Canada    7    8
```

I'd like to keep `Year` as an ID variable, but create multiple columns for `VarA` and `VarB`, one for each value of `Country` (I'm not picky about column order), to make the following table:

```
Year VarA.Canada VarA.USA VarB.Canada VarB.USA
2014           0       NA          10       NA
2015           6        1           5        3
2016           7        2           8        2
```

I managed to do this with the following code:

```
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)

data <- as.data.table(read.table(header=TRUE, text='Year Country VarA VarB
2015     USA    1    3
2016     USA    2    2
2014  Canada    0   10
2015  Canada    6    5
2016  Canada    7    8'))

molten <- melt(data, id.vars=c('Year', 'Country'))
molten[,variable:=paste(variable, Country, sep='.')]
recast <- dcast(molten, Year ~ variable)
```

But this seems a bit hacky (especially editing the default-named `variable` field). Can I do it with fewer function calls? Ideally I could just call one function, specifying the columns to drop as IDs and the formula for creating new variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dcast` you can cast multiple `value.var`s at once (from `data.table` v1.9.6 on). Try:

```
dcast(data, Year ~ Country, value.var = c("VarA","VarB"), sep = ".")

#   Year VarA.Canada VarA.USA VarB.Canada VarB.USA
#1: 2014           0       NA          10       NA
#2: 2015           6        1           5        3
#3: 2016           7        2           8        2
```

Comment: I tried this and got the following warning:

`Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds In addition: Warning message: In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @ConnorHarris Make sure your `data` is a `data.table`. Try it with `setDT(data)`

Comment: Also make sure your `data.table` package version is > 1.9.6

Comment: Solved! The problem wasn't that `data` wasn't a `data.table`, but rather that the `reshape2` import masked the `data.table` version of `dcast` with its own. Removing `require(reshape2)` fixed this. My `data.table` version is `1.10.4`, incidentally.

Comment: Nice, if you want to have both loaded you could also do: `data.table::dcast(...)`